# Powershell - call to document library does not have items

Tags: 2010, powershell

I am using Powershell to iterate through items in a document library and when I am running the ISE debugger there are no items in my list. I can see that the list is recognized, but I do not see any items.

Here's what I am attempting:

```
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("https://site")
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$docLib = $web.GetList("https://site/docs") 

# $docLib.Items is blank
$items = $docLib.Items
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

When I use `SPWeb.GetList()` I use a relative path like:

```
$docLib = $web.GetList("/Web/Lists/ListName")
```

If the actual path to the library is `https://site/docs` then try:

```
$docLib = $web.GetList("/docs")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$docLib = Get-SPList -URL "https://site" -Title "DocLib Title"
$items = $docLib.Items
foreach ($item in $items)
{
 write-host $item.Name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$list.Items | foreach-object { $_.Name }
```